# Javascript return Flot graph object

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Can I´m asking for advice. I have function which should return javascript object

```
function get_temp(){
    var datasets_temp = {
        "sens1": {data: [[1340803113,22.9],[1340803474,23],[1340803836,23],[1340804197,23.1]] },        
        "sens2": {data: [[1340846482,23],[1340846843,23],[1340847204,23],[1340847566,23]] },
        "sens3": {data: [[1340868157,23.1],[1340868518,22],[1340868879,23.2],[1340869241,23.2]] }};
  return datasets_temp; 
}
```

Drawing graph:

```
var plot = $.plot($("#temp_graph"), get_temp(), $.extend(true, {}, options, {
        xaxis: {min: 0, max: 50}}));
```

I don´t know where is problem why is it not working.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: could you http://jsFiddle.net it?

Comment: I am expecting graph of temperature. 
I tried jsFiddle but still have problems with returning of variable(object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the series data needs to be an array of series objects, not just one object with each set of data being a property of it.

What you should have is something like this:

```
var dataset_temp = [  //an array
  {   //of series objects
     label: 'sens1',
     data: [[1340803113,22.9],[1340803474,23],[1340803836,23],[1340804197,23.1]]
  },
  {
     label: 'sens2',
     data:  [[1340846482,23],[1340846843,23],[1340847204,23],[1340847566,23]]
  },
  {
     label: 'sens3',
     data: [[1340868157,23.1],[1340868518,22],[1340868879,23.2],[1340869241,23.2]]
  }
];
```

You have another problem, which is that you are obviously plotting the x-axis as time, but your timestamps (i.e. `1340846482`) are not javascript timestamps, they are "unix" ones.  What you need to do is multiply every timestamp by 1000 (i.e. `1340846482000` is correct), because javascript counts them in milliseconds, not seconds.  See the text in [this example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html) for other caveats.

Comment: Thank you Ryley! You are right. I fixed my code according your advice and now works.